# fatal: Not a git repository: git status works. But git add . doesn't

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I've had a gitsubmodule which I failed to properly uninstall. (Guessing here). I added a subtree with the same name. And everything went fine until I should stage my files.

```
$git status /*Shows unstaged files just fine*/
$git add . /*Prints error message*/

fatal: Not a git repository:MyProject/SLibrary/../.git/modules/SLibrary
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of the error message so I can stage my files with git add -a/.

Comment: Is `stat` a special alias? I get `git: 'stat' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: Sorry. I meant status (I use stat as allias for git status --oneline)

Comment: I suspect that you just have just have to manually remove the section specific to the submodule from `.git/config` manually a this stage.

Comment: If you remember it, add to the question the command you used to add the subtree. Also add the printout of `git submodule` and the contents of any `submodule` section in the `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen when trying to move a submodule outside its git repository.

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/some-project
```

Check for a `.git` file in the project. It may have a relative path to its old `gitdir`.

```
$ cat .git
gitdir: ../.git/modules/some-project
```

Update that file or remove it and `git init`.

Comment: .git should be a directory, not a file.

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny in this case `.git` refers to a file, not directory. Git submodules can have a `.git` file which points to the directory holding the git config file for the remote.